# Twilio voice package for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, twilio

Anybody know about any Twilio voice client package for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS? Officially or any binding library? I am looking for this for about a week also submitted a support request to Twilio but no reply yet.

Answer (score 2):

As I know Twilio stopped working on Xamarin bindings. So nothing official yet. I suggest you to check out unofficial Xamarin bindings, there are some of them on github, so there is no need to write your own.

We're using Twilio SDKs with Xamarin for apps in Google Play and App Store, so we're trying to support and update bindings regularly and publishing them as nuget packages.

I'm providing the link for reference: https://github.com/dkornev/TwilioXamarinBindings

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20896846)

Comment: @Seth Thanks! I've edited the answer. I hope that will help Xamarin devs to use twilio sdks in their apps

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid we do not currently have an official Xamarin package for the [Twilio Programmable Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk).